# When click on notification app does not run MainActivity in Android [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I have been trying to implement repeating local notifications in my android app and I have achieved this pretty well (I believe) but when I want to click on my notification and execute a logic in it it 1. Does not start the MainActivity (Does not launch me to the app) 2. Does not execute any logic

In my MainActivity.cs file I have the LaunchMode set to SingleTop as well I have the respective override of the method OnNewIntent() that will recieve my notification when I click on it, but it just simply does not execute that method even

I send my notification with a BroadcastReceiver that I call in other class that is NOT the MainActivity.cs (because I have seen many people does that) thanks to my implementation of the Interface that communicates with my shared code project.

Method that calls the notification:

```
public void ScheduleNotification(string title, string message, long seconds)
    {
        if (!channelInitialized)
            CreateNotificationChannel();

        NotificationReciever.title = title;
        NotificationReciever.message = message;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(NotificationReciever));
        intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
        intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(AndroidApp.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + seconds * 1000, 2000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

My broadcast receiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled =true)]
    public class NotificationReciever : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        const string channelId = "default";
        public static string title = "";
        public static string message = "";
        const string channelName = "Default";
        const string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;

        public const string TitleKey = "title";
        public const string MessageKey = "message";

        int messageId = -1;
        NotificationManager manager;
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
               .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
               .SetContentTitle(title)
               .SetContentText(message)
               .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.OlympiaLogo))
               .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.OlympiaLogo)
               .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

            manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);
            var notification = builder.Build();
            manager.Notify(messageId, notification);
        }
    }
```

And finally my MainActivity.cs (the one that doesn't get executed when I click on notification):

```
[Activity(Label = "LocalNotificationsApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent);

        LoadApplication(new App());
        //
        //AndroidNotificationManager.alarmManager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        CreateNotificationFromIntent(intent);
    }

    void CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent?.Extras != null)
        {
            string title = intent.Extras.GetString(AndroidNotificationManager.TitleKey);
            string message = intent.Extras.GetString(AndroidNotificationManager.MessageKey);
            if(title != null && message != null)
                DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>().ReceiveNotification(title, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be setting the wrong intent when you create your push notifications. For my push notifications I set the intent for it as the main activity. Try                 Intent intent = new Intent(this.Application, typeof(MainActivity));

Comment: doesnt work beacuse in my second paramete of intent ctor I'm setting the broadcast that I'm using

Comment: @AndresCastro But i have a question, what do you mean by the parameter this.Application? when I reference it just simply does not exist

Comment: I'm using firebase so this.Application is part of the service. As long as you have the context that is fine.

I think you need to create a new intent inside of NotificationReciever instead of using the one that is passed in and copy the bundle into the new intent otherwise MainActivity won't launch.

Comment: @AndresCastro sorry, i'm not using firebase, i'm using local notifications, also can you provide me a sample code please of your suggestion?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a brand new intent and using the main activity instead of reusing the activity passed into `OnReceived`

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled =true)]
public class NotificationReciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    const string channelId = "default";
    public static string title = "";
    public static string message = "";
    const string channelName = "Default";
    const string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";
    const int pendingIntentId = 0;

    public const string TitleKey = "title";
    public const string MessageKey = "message";

    int messageId = -1;
    NotificationManager manager;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // pull stuff from old intent.
        string title = intent.Extras.GetString(TitleKey);
        string message = intent.Extras.GetString(MessageKey);

        // Instead of using intent that is passed in. Create a new one.
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        var bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.PutString(TitleKey, title);
        bundle.PutString(MessageKey, message);
        mainIntent.PutExtras(bundle);
        mainIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.OlympiaLogo))
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.OlympiaLogo)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

        manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);
        var notification = builder.Build();
        manager.Notify(messageId, notification);
    }
}
```